# How to run multiple terminals on remote ubuntu server through ultravnc?

Tags: server, vnc, vncviewer

I am trying to simultaneously run multiple instances of my application from terminal on remote ubuntu server. Single terminal is required for running a single instance of application. I am accessing remote server through putty and ultravnc viewer.

Every time there is a network issue in my local machine(which has windows 7 as OS), application running through putty gets abruptly terminated with a message network error which is understandable. It wastes my time as i have to run application again and again from starting.

By using ultra vnc viewer, application runs independently of network issue in my local setup. But i can run my application only through single terminal. When i try to execute multiple instances of vnc viewer, it shows same terminal.

I want to work on multiple terminals via vnc viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) would be a nice solution to your problem. It is a terminal multiplexer.

> What is a terminal multiplexer? It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal.

[Screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) is another option. This binary ships with Ubuntu by default.

I prefer Tmux above Screen. Tmux can split screens, has a statusbar and support Vi like key bindings which, for as far as I know, Screen does not support.